# Differnce in between Android 4.2.2 and 4.2.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, htc-one-x

Just updated my HTC One X from **cm-10.1-20130119** to **cm-10.1-20130304-EXPERIMENTAL**.

The only difference I noticed is my android is now on **4.2.2** from **4.2.1**.

Can anyone list me difference in between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Android is concerned, 4.2.1 to 4.2.2 contained only a few things. They include:

- Show remaining time for downloads from the Play Store
- Provide a system notification sound when wireless charging begins
- Allows long-pressing on certain tiles in Quick Settings

In reality, since you have a device that doesn't support wireless charging, the second point obviously doesn't apply to you. And since CM already heavily modified the tiles for Quick Settings and offers far more options that this update introduced, the only benefit you would get out of this update would be showing the remaining time.

But, CM has new features being added all the time that are separate of the features added by Google. If you look under Settings -> About Phone -> View Changelog, you can see a big list of all the major features that CM 10.1 adds to Google's Android 4.2.2 release.

And if you want to look at all the specific changes (usually around 10-50 per day, although, some are new features, some are bug fixes for devices not related to yours, and some are new/updated translations), you can see it online at http://changelog.bbqdroid.org and clicking on your device and CM version. You can browse through the changes for each nightly there, and although some of the subjects can be cryptic, you can still usually make out what new features are being introduced.

Answer (score 0):

If you could see the official [Android web page](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/), the section `What's new in Android 4.2, Jelly Bean` enumerates all the changes in detail.  Though it is the delta from 4.1 and not from 4.2.1 as you had asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to look at wikis

Then wikipedia has a changelog for it >>> [click me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.2_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_17.29)

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is that which you might notice that 4.2.1 show the total space of those apps greater than 1GB like asphalt 8, GTA san andreas etc while 4.2.2 just shows the total apk size so 4.2.1 is better in this case!